# Cassandra Achilles: One to many mapping

Tags: java, cassandra, orm, cassandra-3.0

I am using Cassandra 3.6 with Achilles. I have below designed table in Cassandra.

```
CREATE TABLE userVehicles (
  userid text,
  name text static,
  surname text static,
  vehicleNum text,
  vehicleMake text,
  vehicleModel text,
  vehicleYear text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
```

I will be having many vehicles attached to single User and when I will select with UserId, I should get User details and all vehicle belongs to him.

How to map this in Achilles??

Updating table

```
CREATE TYPE Vehicle(
---------
)
```

And then in userVehicles table

```
vehicleDetails LIST<FROZEN<Vehicle>>
```

Tried Achillies mapping

```
@Table(keyspace="keyspace", table="userVehicles")
public class UserDetails{

    @PartitionKey(value = 1)
    private String userid ; 

    @Column
    private String name ;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @Column
    private List<@Frozen Vehicle> vehicle;
}

@UDT(keyspace="keyspace", name="vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

    @Column
    private String vehicleNum ; 

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String vehicleMake ;

    @Column
    private String vehicleModel ; 

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String vehicleYear ;

}

@Configuration
@CompileTimeConfig(cassandraVersion = CassandraVersion.CASSANDRA_3_7)
public class AchillesConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ManagerFactory managerFactory;

    @Bean
    public User_Manager userEntityManager(){
        return managerFactory.forUser(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: what achilles mapping code you have?

Comment: Updating my Achilles mapping

Comment: any particular problems you have with this mapping?

Comment: I am getting NullPointer for ManagerFactory at server startup. I have injected it. But seems like its not getting injected because of some mapping issue.

Comment: share the exception trace please as well as the initialization code

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManager' defined in class path resource [/..../.../AchillesConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public info.archinnov.achilles.generated.manager.Vehicle_Manager /.../..../AchillesConfiguration.userEntityManager()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Updated the question with initialization code. I have used some dummy name of classes. But relation is same.

Comment: It was my mistake. Somehow Inject was not working. When replaced with Autowired, it started working. But don't know, how it was working for Single simple table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is updated in mapping above. For nested tables, this is the way you should go in Cassandra with Achilles framework.